# 301 Redirecting a URL with a long dash

Tags: rewrite, 301-redirect

On a site I'm looking after I need to do a 301 redirect on a URL which has a long dash in it, but it is not working. My redirect is in UrlRewriting.config, and is as follows:

```
<add name='blog1' virtualUrl='^~/news/blog/2011/08/cookies-%E2%80%93-crunch-time-for-website-operators$' destinationUrl='/news/blog/2011/08/crunch-time-for-website-operators' redirect='Application' ignoreCase='true' redirectMode='Permanent' />
```

As you can see there is a long dash with a hyphen either side.

Any idea why this redirect would not be working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working by doing the rewrite with ISAPI_Rewrite rather than UrlRewriting.config. And to do so I used the following rule: Note, I didn't have to put the encoded version of the long dash in.

```
# Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite configuration file
# Version 3.1.0.73

# basic settings, DO NOT CHANGE THESE
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase 

RewriteRule ^/news/blog/2011/08/cookies-–-crunch-time-for-website-operators /news/blog/2011/08/crunch-time-for-website-operators [R=301,L]
```